# No properties in LocalStorage ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, local-storage

After sending information to `localstorage`, no data is saved and {} no properties are received.

```
const Signin = () => {

    const [values, setValue] = useState({ email: "", password: "" });

    const onChangeInput = (e) => {
        const { name, text } = e.target;
        setValue(pvalue => ({
            ...pvalue,
            [name]: text,
        }));

    };

    function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(values));
    };


    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <p>
                    <label>Email address:</label><br />
                    <input
                        name="email"
                        value={values.email}
                        onChange={onChangeInput}
                    />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Password:</label><br />
                    <input
                        name="password"
                        value={values.password}
                        onChange={onChangeInput}
                    />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <button id="btn" type="submit">Register</button>
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Signin;
```

After sending the profile with the submit button, the entered information is not saved in localstorage and in localstorage , {} no properties are displayed

Answer (score 2):

get value from targeted input insted of text.

```
const onChangeInput = (e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  setValue((pvalue) => ({
    ...pvalue,
    [name]: value,
  }));
};
```

Comment: thank you
Is it possible to explain this problem?

Comment: only get the value of input from e.target.value

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).